# Jquery check parents checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the code bellow. Here `AAA` and `BBB` is root parent menu. What i already did is When i click `AAA` then it checks all its child checkboxes and also when i click `AAA1` it selects all its child checkbox. But problem is when a child checkbox is checked then its main root parent menu also should be checked and this not works. Check the Jquery part. I already tried like `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.parent_checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);` but this not selects its root parent. How can i fix it?

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g07bzwx6/)

Jquery:

```
$("body").on("change", ".parent_checkbox", function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.child1_checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.child2_checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
    $("body").on("change", ".child1_checkbox", function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.child2_checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
    $("body").on("change", ".child2_checkbox", function () {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.parent_checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
```

Html:

```
<div class="accordion-group" id="CollapsibleItemPlaceHolder">
  <div class="EachCategorySet">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#child_b1045" aria-expanded="true"><small>AAA</small></a>
      <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox parent_checkbox" name="selectall" value="1045"><span data-ripple="" class="bg-primary-darker checkmark"></span></label></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child_b1045" class="accordion-body collapse show">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#child_c1047" aria-expanded="true"><small>AAA1</small></a>
              <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox child1_checkbox" name="selectall" value="1047"><span data-ripple="" class="bg-primary-darker checkmark"></span></label></div>
            </div>
            <div id="child_c1047" class="accordion-body collapse show">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="" data-toggle="" href="#child_c1048"><small>AAA2</small></a>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox child2_checkbox" name="selectall" value="1048"><span data-ripple="" class="bg-primary-darker checkmark"></span></label></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="child_c1047" class="accordion-body collapse show">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="" data-toggle="" href="#child_c1049"><small>CCC</small></a>
                    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox child2_checkbox" name="selectall" value="1049"><span data-ripple="" class="bg-primary-darker checkmark"></span></label></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="EachCategorySet">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#child_b1046"><small>BBB</small></a>
      <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-container"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox parent_checkbox" name="selectall" value="1046"><span data-ripple="" class="bg-primary-darker checkmark"></span></label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AAA is not parent of AAA1, BBB1 and CCC html speaking

Comment: aha @Frenchy is correct. `AAA` is in another div. Anyways but how to fix it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at parents() and closest(). With closest(), you can search for the closest parent of an element triggering an event that you know of and use that to find another item:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input', function() {
  $(this).closest('.the-parent-that-i-need').find('.another-item').doStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Frenchy described i have to search  outside parents. I fixed this like bellow:

```
$(this).closest('.EachCategorySet').find(".parent_checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
```